# Flutter tests error on CI server after SDK upgrade

Tags: linux, flutter, docker

Working on upgrading an app from using Flutter SDK 2.0.6 to 2.8.1.  Updated all the tests so that they pass locally on Intel Macbook Pro.  Upgraded the docker image our CircleCI server uses to point to use the new SDK.  The docker file looks like:

```
FROM circleci/android:api-30

RUN sudo apt-get install -y locales
RUN sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
RUN /usr/sbin/locale-gen C.UTF-8
ENV LANG='C.UTF-8' LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'

RUN curl https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_2.8.1-stable.tar.xz -o /tmp/flutter.tar.xz && \
  sudo tar -xvJ -C /opt -f /tmp/flutter.tar.xz && \
  sudo chown -R circleci:circleci /opt/flutter && \
  rm -f /tmp/flutter.tar.xz

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/opt/flutter/bin"
```

Now some of the unit tests on the CI server fail with the following error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following SocketException was thrown running a test:
Connection failed (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2), address =
/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket, port = 0

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:681:35)
```

I'm a little out of my depth with running flutter in a CI server.  What does that error mean, and what steps can I take to troubleshoot?

Later on in the stack trace it is `ConnectivityLinux._startListenConnectivity (package:connectivity_plus_linux/src/connectivity.dart:61:20)`

Comment: Can you add a minimal example for a test which would pass with Flutter SDK 2.0.6 but does not pass with Flutter SDK 2.8.1?

Comment: The difference is between SDK 2.8.1 running locally, and SDK 2.8.1 running on the CI server.  Looking at the test it is because of the package connetivity_plus_linux.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to pass in a mocked [connectionStream](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-flutter/blob/4bddff5918580775d631cdf81edb9bff54d7d3df/packages/stream_chat_flutter_core/lib/src/stream_chat_core.dart#L47) in my tests.